# Automate time management using Python & google calendar

Tags: python, automation

After running the code, I didn't encounter any errors. However, when I checked my Google Calendar, I noticed that no events were recorded. I'm not sure why this is happening, so I'm posting here. If anyone has had a similar experience or knows the solution, please leave a comment.

Here is the code snippet that is supposed to save data to Google Calendar whenever a signal is received:

````
```SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
logger = logging.getLogger('google_calendar')  # Get the custom logger

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def create_event_on_calendar(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_confirmed:
        google_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
        )
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=google_credentials)
        if created:
            # Create a Google Calendar API service object
            service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=google_credentials)        
            # Call the function that creates the event in Google Calendar
                # ...... # omitted .......
            event = {
            .... # omitted .....
        }   
        try:
            event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()        
            logging.info('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))
        except HttpError as error:
            logging.error(f'An error occurred while creating the event: {error}')
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'An error occurred: {e}')```
````

I would appreciate any help or insights on why the events are not getting recorded in Google Calendar.

I connected my application (Python) to the Google Calendar API using server-to-server authentication (google service account). However, when I checked my Google Calendar, I noticed that no events were recorded.

Comment: _supposed to save data to Google Calendar whenever a signal is received_ Well, were any signals received?  That's the first thing to confirm...

Comment: Also, it looks like the function does nothing at all if `instance.is_confirmed` is false.  What is the actual value of that attribute?

Comment: John Gordon: Yes, signals are received, and `if instance.is_confirmed` is false, then no function is executed. This is my intention. True or False, True > signals.py > Google Calendar API

Comment: So were any signals received where `instance.is_confirmed` was true?

Comment: Yes, it was, otherwise nothing happened. (no email response by signals either)

Comment: Then there must be a problem in the code that actually creates the event in google, which you didn't show us...

Comment: Did you try putting this code (everything after `if instance.is_confirmed`) in a standalone script and run it, and see if it works?

Comment: This script works fine in a local environment and  `if instance.is_confirmed`  works fine, which I tested. but I will do it again just in case.

Comment: _This script works fine in a local environment_ Then it seems the problem is not with the code, but with  the environment/configuration...

Comment: After conducting the test again, the code is running without any issues. Everything seems to be functioning correctly, except for the fact that it's not logging to the calendar. This issue arises when trying to authenticate from one server to another using a Google service account. Using a GUI for this task is not meaningful; it's meant for automation. Having to manually log in and do this on each server is not practical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cause of the Issue:
When attempting to use the Google Calendar API, there are two authentication methods available: OAuth client ID and Service Account. I opted for the Service Account approach because using OAuth client ID worked well in the local environment but resulted in errors in the deployment environment. However, even though I successfully obtained server-to-server authentication using Service Account and encountered no errors, I noticed that there were no records in Google Calendar.

The Discovery:
What I discovered is that Google Calendar is originally designed to work exclusively with OAuth client ID. Therefore, even if you authenticate using a Service Account and encounter no issues in your code, you won't get any results.

The Solution:
To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

In your local environment, download credentials.json from the Google Cloud Console.
Execute the script you intend to run locally to obtain token.json.
Move token.json to the root directory of the application deployed in the production environment. This will resolve everything.
When creating credentials in Google, make sure not to select 'web application.' Since a GUI environment won't be available on a production server (avoid downloading and installing it), choose 'desktop app' as the application type when creating credentials. Download this in your local environment to obtain token.json. Then, upload this to the production environment.

Finally, I'd like to demonstrate snippets for authentication and execution using the credentials obtained through OAuth client ID to help with understanding.

```
def create_event_on_calendar(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
 SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

 creds = None
 secure_directory = 'secure/'
 token_file_path = os.path.join(secure_directory, 'token.json')

 if os.path.exists(token_file_path):
     creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file_path, SCOPES)   

 if not creds or not creds.valid:
     if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
         creds.refresh(Request())
     else:
         credentials_file_path = os.path.join(secure_directory, 'credentials.json')
         flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(credentials_file_path, SCOPES)
         creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

     with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
         token.write(creds.to_json())

 service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

 if created:  
 
     ... omitted ...
     event = {... omitted ... }    

 try:
     event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()        
     print('Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')))
    
 except HttpError as error:
     print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```